# Executing SQL in SQLite on the Android SDK

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-emulator

So I've recently completed [this tutorial](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742) and it works great, but I'm a little stuck on reading the data from my database.

I'm now reading from the database file thanks to [Orsol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238123/orsol) by using [this tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) but I'm looking now for a method I can call which will return me the values of a given field. Or at least a method that let's me execute SQL.

The closest I have is by calling this:

```
public List<String> SelectAll()
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM androidtable", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0)); 
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

But this just throws a SQLiteException:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: androidtable: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM androidtable

I do however know that I am loading the correct file (which does have this table), as if I change the directory path or database name, it will fire a run time error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks